# Easy way to integrate JMS, Web Service and RMI with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, jms, rmi

I need to know if there is an easy way to integrate JMS, Web Service and RMI with Java (Server Side). Then, I'd need to integrate that with another technology, such as .NET, Flex or PHP (to get consumed as a Client Side). Where should I start from? Is there any Web Site where I could find some examples about it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Is this a homework exercise or a programming task you were assigned?  It would help if you gave more details and a context.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Yes, it's a homework for college of a subject I took last year (SOA). Basically, I need to integrate two different technologies, like Java and .Net (using JMS, Web Services and RMI). The thing is I'm kinda lost and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please add homework tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different languages I suggest to use webservices or jms, some examples are here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2008/07/19/how-to-call-a-java-ee-web-service-from-a-net-client.aspx

http://www.codemesh.com/products/juggernet/examples/jms.html